# Where is transparent view in blender 2.81

Tags: transparency

So, in blender 2.8, you would jump to Transparent view by hitting z > 2. But in blender 2.81 beta, there's no such option and every build I get, there isn't either so it's not a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to go to addon *Interface: 3D Viewport Pie Menu* and find the shading pie in the drop down list and uncheck it, then the default pie menu will come back.

Otherwise ,you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> to enable the *X-Ray Mode*.

Answer (score 1):

The shortcut <kbd>Z</kbd> to show the shading pie menu still exists in Blender 2.81 and 2.82. However it's <kbd>4</kbd> to enable *Wireframe* mode, <kbd>2</kbd> is for the *Material Preview* mode.

[image: Shading pie menu]

You can also enable *Wireframe* mode by clicking on its icon.

[image: Mode]

---

If you're referring to the X-ray mode, it can either be toggled through <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> or by clicking on its icon.

[image: X-ray]

Comment: So there isn't such a thing as Transparent view in blender 2.81?

Comment: You didn't mean wireframe mode? Please explain what you mean then. Are you referring to X-ray? That's a different shortcut than you described in your question in 2.80.

Comment: Are you using a different keymap than the standard one?

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about X-ray mode and yes, I'm using the Fluid-Mantaflow branch of blender 2.81